# Callback when set Wallpaper is clicked in Android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

can anyone tell me how to get callback when setwallpaper is clicked in live wallpaper. I want to do something when a user clicks on set wallpaper...

I have tried many things bt cudnt get it to work..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something in your wallpaper application you can use onCreate() or onResume() function.